# jQuery AJAX call to Slim Framework PHP function pass parameter as null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, frameworks, slim

I'm trying to use slim framework and when I do a POST to enter a record does absolutely nothing. I'm afraid I pass the parameter identified as null because if I allow it in the database, enter a null record.
this is mi Slim PHP.

```
$app-> post("/banda/", function() use($app){
            $nombre=$app->request->post("nombre");
            try{
                $connection = getConnection();
                $dbh = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO banda VALUES(null, ?)");
                $dbh->bindParam(1, $nombre);
                $dbh->execute();
                $banda = $connection->lastInsertId();
                $connection= null;

                $app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
                $app->response->status(200);
                $app->response->body(json_encode($banda));
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        });
```

And this is my JS

```
var API_URI = "http://localhost/banda/";

    function limpiar() {
        $("#form-band input:first-child").val("");
    }
    function nombreBandaEsVacia() {
        return ($("#form-band input:first-child").val().length == 0);
    }
    function getBandaJSON() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            nombre: getBandaNombre()
        });
    }
    function getBandaNombre() {
        return $("#form-band input:first-child").val();
    }
$("#form-band input:last-child").on("click", function createBanda() {
        if (nombreBandaEsVacia()){
            alert("Oops! Completa el formulario!");
        }else{
            // 1.2 JSON.Stringify
            var banda = getBandaJSON();
        };
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            url:API_URI,
            data:banda,
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log(banda);
            },          
            success:function(response, banda) {
                limpiar();
            },    
            error:function(jqXHR, data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
```

My navigator say this:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_91447311.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of it, you are sending a string to your php script instead of key-value pairs.

You can either use something like:

```
data: {'my_banda_json': banda},
```

and parse it at the server-side before you try to insert it.

Or you can just send what you need in a way that the back-end is now expecting it:

```
data: {'nombre': value_of_the_banda_name_field},
```

Comment: @JaviStinson Don't `stringify` it, just return the object so that you send a key-value pair instead of a string.